# Decrypt a file in VIM after failing to decrypt

Tags: vim, google-drive-api

I've managed to successfully encrypt and decrypt my files in Vim with no issues. HOWEVER, I've since started using (and loving) the vim-metarw-gdrive plugin. Here's the issue: opening an encrypted file via metarw syntax does not detect the encryption and prompt for a password. Is there a way to have vim decrypt a file/buffer after its been opened?

Comment: Although the question (if any - there doesn't seem to be one) is probably on topic, what do you expect for an answer?

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed with question.

Comment: There isn't just one encryption protocol. The plugin would have to be extraordinarily targeted for it to work, and obviously it would need access to the key. Best chance is a shell escape that somehow alters the buffer. But in general you'd want the files to be decrypted *before* opening them in a text editor.

Comment: I'm actually talking about the built in encryption mechanism (blowfish2 in this case).

Comment: I know Blowfish and Twofish. I've never heard of Blowfish 2. But that's not that important to the question I think. I'll vote up and star the question as I'm interested to see if the question is answered. If it is I'll certainly vote up any correct answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the key value to nothing (IE `:set key=`) then reloading the document with `:e!` which would reload the file and, once encryption is detected, will prompt for the key in the editor.